# Clarification regarding "--web-renderer auto" option of "flutter build web" command

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

According to this [page](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/web-renderers) there are three options one can specify regarding which web renderer to use when building a flutter web app.
One of the options is `auto` with the provided description:

> auto (default) - automatically chooses which renderer to use. This
> option chooses the HTML renderer when the app is running in a mobile
> browser, and CanvasKit renderer when the app is running in a desktop
> browser.

I am not sure I completely understand the `automatically chooses` part. Does it mean that artifacts for both `html` and `canvaskit` web renderers are built and in runtime it checks whether a request is from mobile or desktop browser and depending on this serves corresponding artifacts?